# Gentzen's result on PA

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory, peano-arithmetic, ordinal-analysis

The Wikipedia [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_analysis) that Gentzen proved that "in modern terms, the proof-theoretic ordinal of PA is $\varepsilon_0$." Further down, the article defines what the "proof theoretic ordinal" of a theory means. However, I'm not sure what this means regarding PA, since PA can only make finitary statements.

Let me elaborate. Define some encoding of the ordinals ${}<\varepsilon_0$ as natural numbers. This encoding allows us to express statements involving ordinals ${}<\varepsilon_0$ in PA. Then, allegedly PA cannot prove transfinite induction using this encoding.

But what does this mean exactly? One option would be using sets: "Suppose $S$ is a set of ordinals such that, for every $\beta<\varepsilon_0$, whenever $\alpha\in S$ for every $\alpha<\beta$, we also have $\beta\in S$. Then $\beta\in S$ for all $\beta<\varepsilon_0$."

But this is an infinitary statement, as far as I understand, so it cannot be stated in PA.

Another option is to have a schema of infinitely many statements, one for each possible formula $\varphi$ (just like the "induction schema" contains infinitely many axioms, one for each possible formula):

"Suppose that for every $\beta<\varepsilon_0$, whenever $\varphi(\alpha)$ holds for every $\alpha<\beta$, we also have $\varphi(\beta)$. Then $\varphi(\beta)$ holds for every $\beta<\varepsilon_0$."

So what is it exactly that Gentzen proved? Presumably PA can prove the above statement for *some* formulas $\varphi$. So did Gentzen find some *specific* $\varphi$ for which PA cannot prove the above statement? Or what?

Comment: I saw question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5065/ , and it does not answer my question. Over there, the OP wanted to know how you encode ordinals <eps_0 as natural numbers. I understand how you do that

Comment: To answer the first part of the question: yes, transfinite induction is stated as a schema, just like usual induction. When talking about theories weaker than PA we may want to restrict which formulas we include (e.g. only quantifier-free or bounded ones), but for PA and stronger it doesn't matter.

Comment: Noah Schweber has answered your question, but note that the *existence* of some $\varphi$ follows from Gentzen's consistency proof. Namely, if there were no such $\varphi$, then by mimicking Gentzen's consistency proof, we would be able to prove the consistency of PA within PA itself.

Comment: I found an online draft of [this book](https://www.logos-verlag.de/cgi-bin/engbuchmid?isbn=3303&lng=deu&id=) (Proof theory, by Herman Ruge Jervell) to be a very accessible introduction to Gentzen's proof and the concepts leading up to it.  The draft is no longer at its old location but

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Gentzen found a single "induction instance" which is PA-unprovable: more-or-less $\varphi(\alpha)$ = "Every sentence with a proof of cut-rank $\alpha$ has a cut-free proof."

Now, this $\varphi$ is a $\Pi^0_2$ formula. If memory serves, this is suboptimal: with some coding work this can be improved from a $\Pi^0_2$ formula to a $\Sigma^0_1$ formula. The basic idea is to assign in a primitive recursive way to each ordinal $\alpha<\epsilon_0$ a sentence $p_\alpha$ and a candidate proof $s_\alpha$ of cut rank $<\alpha$ such that each pair occurs cofinally often, and then look at the formula $\psi(\alpha)$ = "Either $s_\alpha$ is not a proof of $p_\alpha$ or there is a cut free proof of $p_\alpha$."

And I think even *that's* suboptimal - that we can get to the level of $\Delta_0$ - but I'm not sure.

Comment: What's a reference for the claim that things can be improved to a $\Sigma_1$ or $\Delta_0$ formula?